# How to change color of the left aligned text?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to reactjs, i tried to change the color of the left align text using reactjs. Can anybody help me in this?

this would be jsondata in api:

```
{
"message": "Hello everyone",
    "isrespond": true,
},

{
"message": "hi",
    "isrespond": false,

}
```

Can anyone help me in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <Grid.Column floated={ element.isrespond ? "right" : "left"}><p style={{color: element.isrespond ? "blue" : "green",background:element.isrespond ? "yellow" : "cyan"}}> {result.message}</p></Grid.Column>
```

I think this will work. change the required colors. I added botj for color and background. In the above one. its "green" for left and "blue" for right

Comment: Thanks its working great. Can you tell me how to put only date at left handside and name and time on the right handside?

Comment: please provide some code. there is no date, name or time in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
 let leftAlignedColor
 if(element.isrespond == "left"){
    leftAlignedColor = '#000'
 }else{
    leftAlignedColor = null
 }
<Grid.Column floated={ element.isrespond ? "right" : "left"}><p style={{color: `${leftAlignedColor}`}}> {result.message}</p></Grid.Column>
```

its better to use a `<span>,<p>` inside a column as a good practice.

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: @Achinthal - thanks!.. How to show only date at left handside within the message and name and date on right handside?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply a conditional style. This will enable you even pass a specific class name that styles the component.

```
let myStyle = element.isrespond ? {float:"right",color:"blue"} : {float:"left",color:"red"};
<Grid.Column style={myStyle}> {result.message}</Grid.Column>
```

Comment: Thanks! .. Can you help me in displaying the date only at left hand side and name and date in the right hand side

Comment: Yes it worked for me but the problem is i don't want inline styling ... i want the styiling should me in another file. So do we have any option to keep the color in .css file?

Comment: yes just as I showed for the style you can do the same for class. Instead of style use className and pass the correct class name as defined in your css file