# How to show an updated message in the conversation?

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm new to react and i've written my query for this message list for "[How to change color of the left aligned text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58850603/how-to-change-color-of-the-left-aligned-text)" and i've got the solution but now my query is - If i get a new message then it should display down the new message in the conversation but instead of showing the updated message, It is scrolling upwards and showing older message first.

Can anyone help me in this? Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend this library [react-scroll-to-bottom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll-to-bottom). You can see the working demo [here](https://compulim.github.io/react-scroll-to-bottom/).

Comment: Can we use ScrollintoView method for showing updated message if yes, Could you please help me how to declare it.

Comment: are you making a chat app?

Comment: when i use ***scrollintoView*** method then it is showing an error like this - TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined

Comment: Yes i'm making a chat app, I have given scroller using css properties but when i get a new message scroller is remaining at the top. When i scroll down it is showing the updated message. I want the scroller to display an update message first and then we can scroll up for older messages

Comment: you can refer this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwFA3YMfkoc&t=4340s.

Comment: Here they are using socket.io

Comment: seek to the front-end part at the end of the video